# Free XPS Viewer for Mac

Tags: macos, xps, xps-viewer

I can't seem to find one or my google-fu fails me.  Is there one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up installing Microsoft's XPS Viewer into a Virtual Machine and that seems to work fine.  I know, total overkill, but didn't feel like throwing away another hundred bucks.

Answer (score 11):

I use Google Docs to view my XPS files

Comment: Much better approach if you want to convert to pdf, open and click on right side print option, then save as pdf :) like a boss

Answer (score 2):

A free converter web service is available from [XPS2PDF](http://xps2pdf.co.uk/). All you have to do is upload your XPS file, and it will give your a PDF version.

Answer (score 1):

[NiXPS Viewer 2.0.1](http://www.nixps.com/nixps_view_20.html) - This is the only one I can find and it's definitely not free.

It's free to try but costs 75 euros ($99 USD). The editor is 225 euros ($299 USD).

Comment: it does have a FREE demo-download though ;)

Answer (score 1):

I use XPSReader from Mac Appstore... it cost only 15 and does everything I need.
[Here is the link to AppStore](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/xpsreader/id517674346?l=en&mt=12)